# how to get how much days had the customer sumitted post?

Tags: php, mysql

how to get how much days had the customer sumitted post ?
picture tells what I want to get. I don't know how to sum date in mysql as days,any one helps?
need php to do these job?
[image]

```
select ? from table where ?
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so give us that starting point.

Comment: I am not good at mysql, I dont know how to try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT customers_id, SUM(customers_id) as sum_days FROM table GROUP BY customers_id,   DAY(date);
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my guess:

```
SELECT `customers_id`, COUNT(DISTINCT(`date`)) as sum_days
FROM `table` GROUP BY `customers_id`
```

I tried it on a little table I am tinkering with and got following:

```
SELECT author, entry_date FROM table;
+--------+------------+
| author | entry_date |
+--------+------------+
|      5 | 0000-00-00 |
|      8 | 0000-00-00 |
|      8 | 0000-00-00 |
|      8 | 2013-02-28 |
|      8 | 2013-02-28 |
|      8 | 2013-03-02 |
+--------+------------+
```

Tada

```
SELECT author, COUNT(DISTINCT(entry_date)) as num_days 
FROM table GROUP BY author ;
+--------+----------+
| author | num_days |
+--------+----------+
|      5 |        1 |
|      8 |        3 |
+--------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also, this is the result of previous reply on my same table:

```
SELECT author, SUM(author) as sum_days FROM table 
GROUP BY author, DAY(entry_date);
+--------+----------+
| author | sum_days |
+--------+----------+
|      5 |        5 |
|      8 |       16 |
|      8 |        8 |
|      8 |       16 |
+--------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```